# Date Value Inexplicably Changes in REST WS with SpringBoot

Tags: java, rest, web-services, spring-boot

Consider the following json body that I use using Postman to extract or put some values:

```
{
  "server":
    {
      "address":"ITEM-EX30099",
      "port":10500
    },
  "instance":{
    "instance-name":"instance",
    "instance-number":100252,
    "date":"20190429"
  }
}
```

When I was debugging the code, I noticed that all the information that I put in the aforementioned json body don't change, all except for the date value which inexplicably goes from `20190429` to `Mon Dec 31 01:00:00 CET 2018`.

Does someone know why am I having this problem?

Here's the controller's method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{instanceName}/{action}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity putInstanceStatus(@PathVariable(name = "action") String action, @RequestHeader(HeaderFilter.USER_KEY) String username, @RequestHeader(HeaderFilter.PASSWORD_KEY) String password,
                                        @RequestBody ServerInstanceRequestWrapper serverInstanceRequestWrapper)
{
    InstanceActionResponse instanceActionResponse = instanceService.putInstanceStatus(action, username, password, serverInstanceRequestWrapper.getServer(), serverInstanceRequestWrapper.getInstance().getInstanceName(), String.valueOf(serverInstanceRequestWrapper.getInstance().getInstanceNumber()), serverInstanceRequestWrapper.getInstance().getDate().toString());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(instanceActionResponse);
}
```

In the instance class,  here's how I declared the date attribute:

```
@JsonProperty("date")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "YYYYMMdd")
private Date date;
```

Comment: Note that `YYYY` is the _week_ year which might not be what you want. Use `yyyy` instead.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you so much.